# Is there a way to time script download time separately from execution?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I'd like to instrument some timing variables for my main JavaScript load. I could do something like this:

```
<script>
  performance.mark('script-start')
</script>
<script src="something.js"></script>
```

Then somewhere in something.js add a `performance.measure('script-start')`.

The problem is that this would time both the script download time and the script parsing and (part of) the execution time. Is there a way to time script download and execution separately?

Comment: Wouldn't you usually get the download time using `performance.getEntriesByType('resource')`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `performance.measure('script-start')` at the very beginning of `something.js`. This will include the parse time, but not the execution time. Unless the script is enormous, the parse time should be almost negligible.

You could time the download and execution separately by putting `performance.mark('download-start')` in the first `<script>` tag. Then put

```
performance.measure('download-end');
performance.start('script-start');
```

at the beginning of `something.js`.

Comment: Manual testing is definitely showing that parsing is a non-trivial component of our application's latency. But I'd like to be able to measure it in production to be sure.